# Regression Analysis, multivariate analysis

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, genetics

I have a data which looks like this:

```
Tissue  I   p1  p2  p3  p4  p5
t1  20  10.90   0.07    40.57   76.71   12.73
t2  10  13.57   3.48    27.93   75.46   19.59
t3  13  1.05    0.04    16.18   8.92    7.56
```

The second column (I) is my dependent variable and p1 through p5 are my independent variables. I have a much bigger data set than the one I am giving here as an example. p1 through p5 are genes in which I am interested in. I want to know what genes (in this example out of 5) are associated with I.

I want to do multivariate analysis but I am confused because I want to take into account all the genes (around 200 in bigger dataset), and some how want to know which one of them are associated with I(my index). I have looked at `lm` function in R for regression analysis, but I am wondering how can I do this for all 200 genes I have and get the BEST combination of genes may be 10 out of 200 which are best associated with I. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Though question, you seem to discus high-dimensional data. How many observations do you have? (your parameters are around 200 $=p$). Also, are you looking for prediction, or do you want to conduct inference on the effect of the genes? In the case of prediction the Lasso is a friendly method to find a 'small' set of associated variables. When looking at inference the subject is much harder.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the canonical correlation analysis(CCA) algorithm can be of help but it doesn't give you causality only wich gene causes a positive (resp negative) change in your value of intrest.
 You can look this up in

- Alvin C. Rencher, Methods of Multivariate Analysis (chapter 11)
- Alessio Farcomeni, Robust Methods for Data Reduction (chapter 5)

Last one is the best I think since it give "concrete" exemple on how to use it

PS: CCA works with two data sets and try to find linear projections wich are maximally correlated so you will have to split your dataset in two to use it.